# How to transpose rows of data into a single row with different columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Currently I have data from #temp where I extract it from other tables. The #temp table format is as follows

```
WorkerID MainDoc    SubDoc    Value   TimeStamp
-------- --------  ---------  -----   ---------
1224       Doc1       A1       abc     11:40
1234       Doc1       A2       def     11:40
1224       Doc1       B1       30      11.40
1234       Doc1       B2       40      11:40
1224       Doc1       C1       50      11:40
1234       Doc1       C1       51      11:50
1224       Doc1       C2       60      11:40
1234       Doc1       C2       61      11:50
1235       Doc1       A1       fgf     11:55
1235       Doc1       A2       vbv     11:55
```

I need to transpose this rows into one single row with the lastest timestamp value when `WorkerID` is the same and the format is as follows

```
WorkerID  MainDoc   Value(1)   Value(2)  Value(3)   Value(4)   Value(5) Value(6)
--------  -------   --------   --------  --------   --------   -------- --------
  1234    Doc1      abc        def        30          40         51      61
  1235    Doc1      fgf        vbv       NULL        NULL       NULL    NULL
```

As such how do I go about doing this! Thanks!

Comment: google CROSSAPPLY  https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1958/sql-server-cross-apply-and-outer-apply/

Comment: Your timestamp values are inconsistent. The first two values use a colon and the others use a dot for separating hours from minutes. Should that be corrected first? Or should it work as-is?

Comment: Which SQL version are you using??

Comment: Sorry about the timestamp, I have make changes to it and I am currently using MS SQL 2014

Comment: @VirVir sorry for my original answer, I couldn't test it and it was full of errors and deservedly downvoted, is fixed now...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**My apologizes since the original answer has some logic errors, finally I could get some time to test it**

```
CREATE TABLE #MyTable (workerid int, maindoc varchar(5), subdoc varchar(2), value varchar(3), timestamp varchar(5))

insert #MyTable values 
(1234, 'Doc1', 'A1', 'abc', '11:40'),
(1234, 'Doc1', 'A2', 'def', '11:40'),
(1234, 'Doc1', 'B1', '30' , '11.40'),
(1234, 'Doc1', 'B2', '40' , '11:40'),
(1234, 'Doc1', 'C1', '50' , '11:40'),
(1234, 'Doc1', 'C1', '51' , '11:50'),
(1234, 'Doc1', 'C2', '60' , '11:40'),
(1234, 'Doc1', 'C2', '61' , '11:50'),
(1235, 'Doc1', 'A1', 'fgf', '11:55'),
(1235, 'Doc1', 'A2', 'vbv', '11:55');
```

In this approach, my first step is to use a CTE to get the ValueNumber and take the last value for each SubDoc, then I Pivot the values....

```
WITH subDocs AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SubDoc) vn, SubDoc FROM (SELECT DISTINCT SubDoc FROM #MyTable) A
), cte AS (
    SELECT 
        WorkerID, 
        MainDoc, 
        T.SubDoc,
        Value,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY WorkerID, MainDoc, T.SubDoc ORDER BY TimeStamp DESC) AS rn, 
        vn
    FROM #MyTable T
    JOIN subDocs S ON T.subdoc = S.subdoc 
)
SELECT WorkerID, MainDoc, [1] as [Value(1)], [2] as [Value(2)], [3] as [Value(3)], [4] as [Value(4)], [5] as [Value(5)], [6] as [Value(6)]
FROM (
    SELECT WorkerID, Maindoc, vn, Value FROM cte WHERE rn = 1
) Source
PIVOT (
    MAX(Value) FOR vn IN ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6])
) PVT
```

But most probably the number of columns that you want is not fixed, and you need to use dynamic SQL to get it

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @SubDocCount INT
DECLARE @ColumnNames NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @PivotValues NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT TOP 1 @SubDocCount = COUNT(DISTINCT Subdoc) FROM #MyTable

;WITH cols AS (
    SELECT 1 as num
    UNION ALL
    SELECT num + 1
    FROM cols WHERE num < @SubDocCount 
)
SELECT 
    @ColumnNames = STUFF(
             (SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(CAST(num AS VARCHAR)) + ' AS ' + QUOTENAME('Value' + QUOTENAME(CAST(num AS VARCHAR),'('))
              FROM cols
              FOR XML PATH (''))
             , 1, 1, ''),
    @PivotValues = STUFF(
             (SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(CAST(num AS VARCHAR)) 
              FROM cols
              FOR XML PATH (''))
             , 1, 1, '')

SET @SQL = N'
    WITH subDocs AS (
        SELECT DISTINCT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SubDoc) vn, SubDoc FROM (SELECT DISTINCT SubDoc FROM #MyTable) A
    ), cte AS (
        SELECT 
            WorkerID, 
            MainDoc, 
            T.SubDoc,
            Value,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY WorkerID, MainDoc, T.SubDoc ORDER BY TimeStamp DESC) AS rn, 
            vn
        FROM #MyTable T
        JOIN subDocs S ON T.subdoc = S.subdoc 
    )
    SELECT WorkerID, MainDoc, ' + @ColumnNames + '
    FROM (
        SELECT WorkerID, Maindoc, vn, Value FROM cte WHERE rn = 1
    ) Source
    PIVOT (
        MAX(Value) FOR vn IN (' + @PivotValues + ')
    ) PVT'

EXEC (@SQL)
```

**Note** there are 3 different WorkerID's in your sample input, given the expected result I assumed 1224 and 1234 as a typo