# How do I merge records in the same table in SQL Server 2014 using timestamp as reference

Tags: sql, sql-server

Currently I have a table after using PIVOT() with the format and data values as follows

```
NameID   DocumentName   Time  Value1  Value2  Value3  Value4  Value5
------   ------------   ----  ------  ------  ------  ------  ------
2221        Doc1        1053    23      24      25     NULL    NULL     
2221        Doc1        1153    31      32      NULL    28      30
2221        Doc2        1253    NULL    NULL    NULL    40      41  
2222        Doc3        1053    03      06      09      12      15
```

I need to merge record 1,2,3 with the latest values into one single row, where the format would be like this.

```
NameID       Value1   Value2  Value3  Value4  Value5
------       ------   ------  ------  ------  ------
2221         31       32      25      40      41    
2222         03       06      09      12      15
```

It would use timestamp as reference to decide  what values to update and which values will be kept. Any help or start would be appreciated for me to carry on my work!

Comment: So you just want the `MAX()` of each value for each nameid? What have you tried?

Comment: what you have posted is already a result of `PIVOT`. Instead of trying to get what you want from that, why not you post the original table with sample data. It might be easier to starts from there

Comment: can you put up the same data before PIVOT?? Now the structure seems very complex to get what you want.

Comment: and should the DocumentName be Doc2, Doc3 in the output, instead of Doc1, Doc3?

Comment: i remove the document name coloumn, not sure the formatting is correct as currently i am using my phone

Comment: What's the difference with your other question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55507627/how-to-transpose-rows-of-data-into-a-single-row-with-different-columns-in-sql-se/55510869#55510869

Comment: @VirVir It's already taking the last value for each value, you just need to adapt the partitions to your new requirement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is tricky.

Without knowledge about the `pivot` query itself, perhaps the simplest method is correlated subqueries or `apply`:

```
select nameId,
       (select top (1) t2.documentname
        from t t2
        where t2.nameId = t.nameId and t2.documentname is not null
        order by t2.time desc
       ) as documentname,
       max(time) as time,
       (select top (1) t2.value1
        from t t2
        where t2.nameId = t.nameId and t2.value1 is not null
        order by t2.time desc
       ) as value1,
       (select top (1) t2.value2
        from t t2
        where t2.nameId = t.nameId and t2.value2 is not null
        order by t2.time desc
       ) as value2,
       . . .
from t;
```

Comment: where does the name coloumn comes from?

Comment: @VirVir . . . It is now `nameid` as it should have been all along.

Answer (score 0):

I can not see any difference between this and your question here...

[How to transpose rows of data into a single row with different columns in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55507627/how-to-transpose-rows-of-data-into-a-single-row-with-different-columns-in-sql-se/55510869#55510869)

The answer I gave you is already taking the last values before do the pivot, if this is a new requirement you probably just need to adapt the partitions to it...

Anyway, If that is not possible and assuming that you are using SQL Server 2014 for this requirement too, then you can use LAST_VALUE over your current approach

```
WITH YourPivot AS (
    <Put your current pivot code here>
)
SELECT DISTINCT 
    NameID
    ,LAST_VALUE(Value1) OVER (PARTITION BY NameID ORDER BY CASE WHEN Value1 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, [Time] ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) Value1
    ,LAST_VALUE(Value2) OVER (PARTITION BY NameID ORDER BY CASE WHEN Value2 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, [Time]  ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) Value2
    ,LAST_VALUE(Value3) OVER (PARTITION BY NameID ORDER BY CASE WHEN Value3 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, [Time]  ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) Value3
    ,LAST_VALUE(Value4) OVER (PARTITION BY NameID ORDER BY CASE WHEN Value4 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, [Time]  ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) Value4
    ,LAST_VALUE(Value5) OVER (PARTITION BY NameID ORDER BY CASE WHEN Value5 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, [Time]  ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) Value5
FROM YourPivot
```